# Any simpler way doing the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

Any simpler ways in doing the determinant=0 and solve for the $lambda$?

\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda -1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 2& \lambda -2  &2 \\ 
0 &2  & \lambda -3
\end{vmatrix}

Sarrus rule seems not so easy?, should expand all, and to factor,

\begin{align*}\lambda ^3-6\lambda ^2+3\lambda +10=(\lambda -5) (\lambda -2) (\lambda +1)\end{align*}(how to factor?)

Comment: So; you are just stuck at the last line? I mean factoring.

Comment: @BabakS. yes, that's one point, if there is an easier way,good to know.

Comment: the characteristic polynomial is $$\left(x-3\right)\,\left(x-2\right)\,\left(x-1\right)-4\,\left(x-1
 \right)-4\,\left(x-3\right)$$ (by Sarrus), this is equal to $$x^3-6\,x^2+3\,x+10$$. Integer solution must be divisors of th constant term. so $$\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 5, \pm 10$$ you have to check. Finally you get $$\left(x-5\right)\,\left(x-2\right)\,\left(x+1\right)$$

Comment: so what is complicate when using the Sarrus rule?

Comment: @miracle173 ah,that's useful to factor use the divisors. How to not use Sarrus rule? by row manipulation?

Comment: @miracle173 the complicate is should expand to get a polynomial of degree 3...

Answer (score 1):

With [Determinant Expansion by Minors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeterminantExpansionbyMinors.html), we have:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda -1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 2& \lambda -2  &2 \\ 
0 &2  & \lambda -3
\end{vmatrix}=(\lambda -1)\begin{vmatrix}
 \lambda -2&2 \\ 
2 & \lambda -3
\end{vmatrix}-2\begin{vmatrix}
 2& 2\\ 
 0& \lambda -3
\end{vmatrix}+0\begin{vmatrix}
 2& \lambda -2 \\ 
0 & 2
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: well, this seems the same to Sarrus rule...

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the matrix into an upper or lower triangular matrix and then multiply along the diagonal.

Comment: but how to convert?

Comment: It's a $3\times 3$ matrix with plenty of $0$'s in it. It's pretty easy to compute the determinant and solve for $\lambda$?

Comment: yes, can you show me how easy to convert into an upper or lower triangular matrix,

Comment: @realmatrix there may or may not be a way. You can try using row or column operations.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, and failed, that's why I asked the question.